# Creating a VCL form in dll Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, vcl

I have this code that is merely trying to create a form in a DLL. I created the DLL and the form through the RAD studio Berlin IDE. I wanted to just put up a blank form to make sure it was working, unfortunately it is crashing with an EAcess violation (or alternately, an EResNotFound exception with message "Resource TSigForm can not be found"), and I can't figure out what is missing.

DLL code:

```
library SigDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Windows, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  SignatureForm in 'SignatureForm.pas' {SigForm1};

{$R *.res}

var
  SigForm: TSigForm;

procedure PrepareSigDLL(AppHandle : HWND); stdcall;
begin
  SigForm := TSigForm.Create(nil);          // <--------- CRASHES HERE
end;

procedure GetSignature(Variables: PChar); stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage('GetSignature called!');
end;

procedure CloseSigDLL; stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage('CloseSigDLL called!');
end;

exports
  PrepareSigDLL,
  GetSignature,
  CloseSigDLL;

begin
end.
```

SigForm code:

```
unit SignatureForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TSigForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  SigForm: TSigForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Generic Host app for DLL:

```
unit SigDllHost;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

  procedure PrepareSigDLL(handle: HWND); stdcall; external 'SigDll.dll';

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrepareSigDLL(Self.Handle);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Start with some debugging. What line of code, probably in the VCL, generates the AV

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It drops me into assembly in rtl90.bpl.

Comment: My advice is to suppress runtime packages and build with debug DCUs enabled. Then when you break you should see Pascal code. Then look at the line which has broken, and the call stack.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Use debug .dcu's" seems to already be set to true. How do I suppress runtime packages?

Comment: In the project options, disable runtime packages

Comment: I un-checked 'Inherit' in Packages > Runtime Packages ("Link with runtime packages" was always false). Now I'm getting a 'Resource TSigForm not found' message, but its still dropping me to assembly.

Comment: Where is your calling code?

Comment: @J... `SigForm := TSigForm.Create(nil);` in the first section of code above.

Comment: No, I mean how are you testing this DLL?  Where is the code that consumes it?

Comment: Its being called from an exe who's source I don't have access to. What are you thinking?

Comment: So why do you think that something is wrong with your code and not theirs?  Getting the calling convention wrong would cause an AV, for example (if they import the function without the `stdcall` decoration).

Comment: You can readily test your DLL from a host that you build

Comment: Well... I think you *need* to rule that out.  We can't guess at what we don't know.  Are you sure the host application is *expecting* this to be a `stdcall` method?  There is nothing wrong with the code you've shown us, otherwise.

Comment: @J... That was the convention I was told to use, so I believe so. Let me make a host app and get back to you.

Comment: @J... I made a generic host app and get the same exception EResNotFound "Resource TSigForm not found".

Comment: That seems implausible. Perhaps something was messed up when you disabled packages.

Comment: @NilsGuillermin This part `'SignatureForm.pas' {SigForm1};`tells me you have at least more versions of the `SigDLL.dll` one version needs `SigForm1` and the other looks for `SigForm`

Comment: @NilsGuillermin, "Resource TSigForm not found" suggests no such resource is linked inside the DLL.  The first step would be to confirm SignatureForm.dfm does really exists, and then that it contains a definition for TSigForm. Alternatively, you could try to call `TSigForm.CreateNew`which will create the form, but won't try to load the DFM associated. That way, you will be able to tell if the DFM is this only issue at hand.

Comment: If I remember correctly, one has to set Application.Handle to AppHandle in PrepareSigDLL. But that was without using packages. No idea whether that's a requirement when using packages since then the Application instance is the same in the executable and the dll.